# DataAdapter error: the column exceeds the MaxLength limit

Tags: c#, dataset

The error occurs when I try populating a datasets datatable.

```
ds = dsMyDataset;
sqlAdapter.Fill(ds, dsMyDataset.MyTable.TableName); // Uses the SQLAdapters 'select command'
```

On fill, I get this error:

***Additional information***: 'Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.'

I run this command in the command window:

```
dsMyDataset.MyTable.GetErrors()[0].RowError
```

And it informs me that "Column 'XMLHistory' exceeds the MaxLength limit."

Odd because in the dataset's length property specifies a length of '2147483647'for that field.

So in my sqladapter I specify a size:

```
sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@XMLHistory", SqlDbType.Text, 2147483647, "XMLHistory");
```

But this apparently does not help my issue out. Also noticed that the size in the DB for that column is '16'.

Now here's an odd thing I noticed. What this program allows me to do is archive data from one DB to another. So I have a list of tables that the user can select from to archive. What's odd is that if I select one table it archives just fine. This issue as I've listed above doesn't actually fire until *after* the first table archives and the system attempts to move on to the second table. The moment it tries to fill the DS, booooom. Dead.

Any suggestions/thoughts appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: I think the problem is not the maximum length of the SQL Parameter, but the maximum length of the column in the database. What kind of database are you using? You say the maximum length of the column in the DB is 16, can you make that bigger?

Comment: SQL Server. I think it would be odd though if the length in sql server was the issue because if I select one table to archive, it does it just fine. And I've confirmed that all of the size prop settings are the same across all of the DBs currently.

Comment: If the first one succeeds, then it seems like it is a `unique` constraint problem. Or the data in the second table has a problem.

Comment: @GlenThomas - unfortunately I can't change the size of that in the DB as I am not an owner.

Comment: @Loathing - Hm. It's odd because all of the data is the same. But I just tried running this one table by itself and it appears that it is having an issue. I'm going to test a few others.

Comment: Well I think you need to change it. Have you tried using data that is less than 16 characters to see if the error persists. Then you could be sure where the problem lies.

Comment: If you have data larger than 16 characters it will not help to make the maxlength setting in the dataset larger. The dataset maxlength is a constraint when you are working with disconnected data to block data coming in the dataset that shouldn't come in and so it should match the database schema size for that field.  When you make a call to update the data, the size of the door is 16. The dataset will not convince your db to take something bigger.

Comment: @eric1825 - Hm. But that's what appears to be happening. The length in the DB is currently set to 16, whereas in my dataset it's the default 2147483647. Of the tables I've test there's only one that appears to not be archiving. Everything else is just fine.

Comment: If it's working for other tables where you increased the dataset maxlength over what the database field size, it only worked because you had data that did not exceed the databases field size limit.  You could tell the dataset column to have a max length of 2147483647 while the db field length is 16 and technically updating the database could even work until some data in that column exceeds 16 characters.  Setting the dataset constraint larger than the db design defeats it's purpose of blocking data early that the database won't receive at update time.

Comment: Just realized that the field in the DB is a text field. Also ran this query on the table in question:
`select max(datalength(myColumn)) from myTable` and found that the longest entry was 12,201. Still seeing the `"Column 'myColumn' exceeds the MaxLength limit."` Thoughts on what that could mean?

Comment: I've seen this error in all cases (until yesterday) when updating the database and didn't break from that inertia.  Just registered your error is happening when you are reading from the database sorry.  By chance could your dataset designer have been created at some length in the past possibly before a design change in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out the issue. One of the xmls that ties to the backend of the dataset itself had a node specifying max length. It was set to 7700. This 7700 was overwriting the property setting in the designer. Not sure how it got set to begin with, but it was super frustrating.

Thanks all for the help.

Comment: My problem was that the dataset designer was not updated with the visual settings. To refresh it, right-click on the dataset and pick `Run custom tool`

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same error when reading a database in an old project.  Was weird because it was reporting cannot exceed length 110 on column B but in the DB design that was the size of its adjacent field A.  I tried a reconfigure on the tabeladapter in the dataset designer and it still acted cross wired on the field max sizes.  I then just dropped the table in the designer and re-added it.  Then it worked.  The database table design had been modified in the database since the xsd was created.

Comment: Yeah I tried that route too. But it was still dead in the water. I did solve this issue and posted above. Thanks for all the help.